# JQuery selector in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I have a loop that iterates thru all rows in a table. Once I am inside of the table i want to get nested values. For example, wins, losses. That would have the html attribute of `[data-stat=wins]`.
This is my code,

```
const result = await request.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/");
const $ = cheerio.load(result);

var teams = [];
var wins = [];
var losses = [];

$('#confs_standings_E > tbody > tr').each((index, element) => {
    var wins = $(element > $('[data-stat=wins]'));
    console.log(wins)
    console.log($(element).text())

})
```

Console.log(wins) returns an empty string. But the line after it returns all rows. This seems pretty simple I've just never used JQuery before so not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you want `var wins = $(element).find('[data-stat=wins]').text();`?

Comment: Can you console.log(element) and see what coming in there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `push()` to add data in your `wins` empty array like this below.

You also need to check on whats coming in `element`- `console.log(element)` and see if data `data-stat=wins` is coming is returned at all.

Once its returning something. Then you the code below to push data in your `wins = []` array

```
const result = await request.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/");
const $ = cheerio.load(result);

var teams = [];
var wins = [];
var losses = [];

$('#confs_standings_E > tbody > tr').each((index, element) => {
    var wins.push($(element > $('[data-stat=wins]')))
    console.log($(element).text())
    console.log(wins)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this if it's only direct children, implied by your inclusion of `>`.

```
$(element).children('[data-stat=wins]'));
```

Or use `.find()` for all descendants.

What you're basically doing is  applying the `>` greater than operator to an element, comparing to see if it's greater than the jQuery object returned by `$('[data-stat=wins]')`. It's valid but not useful.

You're then passing that result to the jQuery function. None of that will produce any kind of desirable result.

Your outer `wins` array is unnecessary, unless you were hoping to maintain an external list of values. More likely you just want to use the values you find in the handler.

Comment: Thats not the  problem here.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping: Focus on your answer. Its syntax is invalid, and the jQuery selection won't produce anything useful. This does what the OP has described.

Comment: Considering he has something already coming from the `element` hence why the issue is that `wins` is empty because that's NOT how to `=` an item to an empty array and expect a value in console log To which what my is answer is referring it to. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping: He's shadowing `wins` with a new variable. It's common for people to do that sort of unnecessary initialization when they're not used to dynamic typing, and they don't know what a jQuery object returns.

Comment: ...but you should still focus on your answer. Its syntax isn't valid, and the jQuery won't work at all.